# Tensorflow object detection API loss increases dramatically

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api, python-3.9

I'm training tensorflow object detection API with my own data but for some reason, all losses seem to skyrocket past some thousands of steps. You can see it on this figure:

[image]

At the beginning it goes down, as it should, but somehow at some point it just explodes.

The model I'm using is ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn with pretrained coco checkpoint but this information might be irrelevant since I think this happens with any model (I've tried 2 models a couple of times each and currently the behaviour is the same for all of my tries). I'm training it following this tutorial https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html so I use the `model_main_tf2.py` script to train the model.

What is very strange is that a colleague of mine does not have this issue. His loss evolution seems rather normal as you can see here:

[image]

He provided me with all the necessary files to run the training (so, the tf.records, the labelmap.txt, the pipeline.config file, the ckpt-0.index etc.). He might be lucky and I'm not. But it's very strange that each time he runs it, he has a normal behaviour and I don't... At least the odds at very very low that this is what happens.

Don't know if it matters but I have a GeForce RTX 3060 Ti, Python: 3.9.6, Tensorflow: 2.5.0, Cudnn: 8.1.1 and Cuda: 11.2
while he has a Geforce GTX 1650 Super, Python: 3.9.6, Tensorflow: 2.5.1, Cudnn: 8.1.0 and Cuda: 11.2

Any idea what could cause this?

Edit 1: I've re-run this while doing nothing else on my computer and it ran quite well. It now shows an expected behaviour. I'll re-run it while using it normally (maybe watch a video or something), which is what I did in the last runs that showed a strange behaviour, and see if this strange behaviour occurs again or not. Do you think it could be the cause of this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I'll have the exact same issue. After a varying number of thousands of steps the loss just explodes. I'm also unsure what could be the cause of the issue.

In my opinion it could either be either an GPU issue or something wrong with the data. But at that point I should have gone through the whole set at least once. Let me know if you make any progress on that :)
[image]

Comment: It feels like the learning rate has a lot to do with this. In the case above, I didn't change the recommended learning rate but changed the batch size (I used a batch size of 2, which does not make much sense, but I cannot go above that before running into memory issues). 
If you change the learning rate to something smaller (basically I divided the batch size by 64, so I divided the learning rate by the same amount) you no longer have this behaviour. But this does not explain everything as my friend just runs batch size 1 and kept the learning rate as is and never ran into this issue